# How do you prove that a particle with the position $(\cos t, \sin t)$ has unit speed?

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametrization

Consider a particle that's motion is given by the vector function
$$
S(t)=(\cos t,\sin t) \, ,
$$
where $t$ is measured in radians. How do you prove that the particle has unit speed, i.e. $|S'(t)|=1$? At first, I thought this would be easy, since $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are simply the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of a particle that has traced an arc of $t$ units anticlockwise around the unit circle. This means that between two points $S(t+h)$ and $S(t)$, the particle must have travelled a distance of $h$ units. Hence,
$$
|S'(t)|=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h}{h}=1 \, .
$$
However, I'm unsure if this solution is actually correct. If I understand correctly, $|S'(t)|$ is the limit of the *displacement* from the initial position, i.e.
$$
|S'(t)| := \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(\cos(t+h)-\cos t)^2+(\sin(t+h)-\sin t)^2}}{h} \, .
$$
In other words, although the particle will have travelled a distance of $h$ units in going from $S(t)$ from $S(t+h)$, its displacement would be something else. However, according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20h%20goes%20to%200%20of%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B%28%5Ccos%28t%2Bh%29-%5Ccos%20t%29%5E2%2B%28%5Csin%28t%2Bh%29-%5Csin%20t%29%5E2%7D%7D%7Bh%7D), the above limit does not even exist. So it seems that I have some misunderstanding of what $|S'(t)|$ actually means, but I'm unsure what it is.

Comment: $S'(t)=(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$, and thus $|S'(t)|=1$.

Comment: @Surb Thanks, that makes sense. However, what was wrong with my reasoning that $$|S'(t)| := \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(\cos(t+h)-\cos t)^2+(\sin(t+h)-\sin t)^2}}{h} \, ?$$

Comment: @Joe: it's also true...

Comment: Your first solution is circular or incomplete. You say that the travelled space is $h$ (presumably because the speed is one ?) and deduce that the speed is one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My idea was that at $S(t+h)$, the particle must have travelled a distance of $t+h$ units along the arc of the unit circle. And at $S(t)$, the particle must have travelled a distance of $t$ units along the arc. Hence, the distance along the arc travelled between $S(t+h)$ and $S(t)$ must have been $h$. However, I'm worried I'm confusing distance with displacement.

Comment: "must have travelled a distance of $t$ units": why on Earth ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Since $S(t+h) = (\cos(t+h),\sin(t+h))$, and sine and cosine are, respectively, the $x$- and $y$- coordinates that after attained after travelling an arc of $t+h$ units around the circle. That's how I'm defining sine and cosine.

Comment: If you take the formula of the arc for granted (which is virtually the same as the formula for the speed), then $\lim\frac hh=1$ is fine. It is not even needed to use calculus, as the speed is constant.

Comment: Why can't you just differentiate and find the modulus of the resulting vector?

Comment: @YvesDaoust My source of confusion is the difference between displacement and distance. Although between $S(t+h)$ and $S(t)$, you have travelled a distance of $h$ units along the arc of the circle, your displacement would be something different. And $|S'(t)|$ involves the limit of the magnitude of the displacement divided by the distance travelled along the arc. So my point is that the solution is not obvious in the sense that you can't just work out $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h}{h}$.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I'm trying to use this in order to understand a proof using vectors that the derivative of sine is cosine. I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: The displacement is just the distance, with a sign, which depends on the convention for the curvilinear abscissa. But you essentially solve this problem without the signs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought displacement was the distance from your starting position as the crow flies, rather than the distance you have travelled along an arc. Although the displacement also comes with a sign, I think there is more to it than that. Is it possible if you elaborate? Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: Do you mean "straight line distance" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes.

Comment: Your discussion is ambiguous. Is it displacement/distance since time $0$, or infinitesimal displacement/distance between times $t$ and $t+h$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Between times $t$ and $t+h$, sorry. And the displacement.

Comment: Then there is no difference between displacement and distance, but possibly the sign.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't understand why this is the case, if the distance along the arc is simply $|h|$, and the magnitude of the displacement (straight line distance) is $\sqrt{(\sin(t+h)-\sin t)^2 + (\cos(t+h)-\cos t)^2}$. As $h$ goes to $0$, do these two become interchangeable?

Comment: The distance simplifies to $\sqrt{2-2\cos h}=2|\sin\frac h2|$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Okay. Thank you very much for the help, Yves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in dropping the absolute value.

$$
|S'(t)| := \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(\cos(t+h)-\cos t)^2+(\sin(t+h)-\sin t)^2}}{|h|} =1.
$$

Comment: So, to clarify, the length of the arc joining $(t+h)$ and $S(t)$ is $|h|$. The magnitude of the displacement from $S(t)$ to $S(t+h)$ is given by
$$
|S(t+h)-S(t)|=\sqrt{\left(\cos(t+h)-\cos t\right)^2 + \left(\sin(t+h)-\sin t \right)^2} \, .
$$

Comment: What your answer shows is that the arc length and the straight line length are asymptotically equivalent. That is,
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\text{arc length}}{\text{straight line distance}} &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|S(t+h)-S(t)|}{|h|}
\\ &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{\left(\cos(t+h)-\cos t\right)^2 + \left(\sin(t+h)-\sin t \right)^2}}{|h|} \\
&= 1
\end{align}
Hence, $|S'(t)|=1$.

Comment: Did I understand your answer properly?

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec{r}(t)=\hat{i}\cos(t)+\hat{j}\sin(t)$$
$$\vec{v}(t)=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=-\hat{i}\sin(t)+\hat{j}\cos(t)$$
$$|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{[-\sin(t)]^2+\cos^2(t)}=1(\therefore)$$